# Play 2.1 - bindFromRequest not working, returning null values

Tags: scala, jquery-mobile, playframework

when I attempt bind form from request, the returned object is set with the initial values.
The form gets displayed correctly.

```
def event(id: Int) = Action {
  val event : Event = Event.event(id)
  Ok(views.html.eventForm(eventForm.fill(event)))}

def update() = Action { implicit request =>
  eventForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.eventForm(formWithErrors)),
    updatedEvent => {
      Event.update(updatedEvent)
      Redirect(routes.Events.all())
    }
  )}
```

When I debug the code I find that the request has both the original data and new for each fields in List. However the `updatedEvent` returned contains the original data from the `event` call.

I am using a custom field constructor, but I don't see how that would cause this issue.

I have looked at numerous examples on Git and not sure what is wrong.

Edit:

Here is debug data from another form when binding request:

form after binding = Map(password -> , email -> )

request = Map(password -> List(, 32131), email -> List(, , some.email@yahoo.com))

The data needed is in the request but does not get binded correctly.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was not with play framework or scala but with jquery mobile.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5590

Issue has been resolved in latest jquery mobile version